# Ag-grid React: Pre-set Filters in Datasource for Infinite Row Model

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Using infinite row model, with sorting and filtering.

As per the documentation, I have handled both sorting and filtering from server-side. Datasource is called every-time i change sort/filter model. But I cannot pre-set the filter model for when its first loaded into the grid. The can't send the initial filter model to the server.

```
const dataSource = {
            rowCount: null,
            getRows: params => {
                    const sortedFilteredData = requestRows(data, params.sortModel, params.filterModel);
                    const rowsThisPage = dataAfterSortingAndFiltering.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
                    const lastRow = -1;
                    if (dataAfterSortingAndFiltering.length <= params.endRow) {
                        lastRow = dataAfterSortingAndFiltering.length;
                    }
                    params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
            }
        };
```

When the datasource is first called the filterOptions is {}.

I have tried setting the model at onGridReady() using api.setFilterModel() but it throws error that we can use setFilterModel with infinite row model type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of ag-grid you are using but you can initialize the filter the problem however is that it will make 2 calls to your datasource when doing so. I started experiencing this after upgrading from v20.0 to v23.1. The code looks like this:

```
    // InitialFilter is just a prop I pass into my grid
    InitialFilter: (params) => {
        let filterComponent = params.api.getFilterInstance("<Your Field Name>");
        filterComponent.setModel({
            type: "greaterThan",
            filter: 0
        });
        params.api.onFilterChanged();
    }
```

I set this in my onGridReady function:

```
    onGridReady(params) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

        // initialFilter prop is set here
        if (this.props.initialFilter) {
          this.props.initialFilter(params);
        }
        params.api.setServerSideDatasource(this.dataSource(params));
    }
```

Additionally, it appears after upgrade to 23.1.0 that if you filter on the same field you set the initial filter on it will do 2 calls to your datasource. There was an issued opened [GitHub Issue 1785](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1785) on this but then closed. Others have provided workarounds but they are all in Angular so I'm trying to figure out how I can do it in React. Hope this helps and if you figure out a workaround in React let me know. :)